# How to write bangla language in iText pdf in android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have  used  bangali Language in itext pdf  in java but it not work  properly My expected output is :প্রযুক্তি শিল্পের দ্রুত
But  actual generated  output is : [image: output]

here is my code

```
try {
                Document document = new Document();
                String encoding = "Identity-H";
                Font fontNormal = FontFactory.getFont(("c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf"), encoding, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 8, Font.NORMAL);
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/lockman/mas.pdf"));
                pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new PDFGenerator());
                document.open();
                document.add(header);       
                Chunk chunkBengali = new Chunk("প্রযুক্তি শিল্পের দ্রুত " + "\n", fontNormal);       
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
                table.addCell("Locale");
                table.addCell("Translated Text");

                PdfPCell cellBengali = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chunkBengali));
                table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Bengali", fontNormal))));
                table.addCell(cellBengali);



                document.add(table);
                document.add(footer);
                document.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PDFGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PDFGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

`

Comment: Are you sure the font you're using knows how to display bangali? If not, try a different font, more specifically a font that supports it.

Comment: I have tried FreeSans.ttf ,ARIALUNI.TTF, and also used supported bangla font  SolaimanLipi.ttf,NikoshBAN.ttf  but not work

Comment: Is there a reason you use Identity-H as encoding?

Comment: how can i solved it

Comment: @Mohammadlockman, did you solve the problem?